# Http WebAPI calling from Https Angular 6 App with SSL not working hosted both in IIS

Tags: ssl, iis, asp.net-web-api, angular6

I have Hosted Angular6 APP and WebAPI on IIS , By default both were http and Everything working fine able to login to application .

Later i have added SSL certificate on Angular 6 APP . Where login page is coming with HTTPS URL but unable to login , it is not calling HTTP WEBAPI from https:// angular Site.

Should i add same certificate to WEBAPI also or keep this https://WEBAPI URL in Environment file in Angular APP.

Please suggest me whats wrong with calling http webapi from https angular app . Is is possible ?

Even i tried by adding Same SSL to WEBAPI also and Updated Environment.ts file with https URL but didn't worked .

Comment: Hi there. Do you get any errors? What can you see in the Developer Tools what is called and what error you receive?

Comment: Hi @Jaques am getting "Unable to get property 'message' of undefined or null reference" after calling API in below code   error => {
                    //this.alertService.error(error);
                    console.log("error data:", error);
                    console.log("error data:", "Error");
                    this.successMessage = "Invalid Credentials!";
                    this.loading = false;
                });

Comment: It is throwing at error at   return this.http.post<any>(this.apiUrl + '/login', { Username: username, Password: password })
            .pipe(map(user => {   .................It is not calling API